# How do I ignore the .aspx extension when using a rewrite map?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7

I have a rewrite map with ~100 old URL to new URL rows:

```
<rewriteMaps>
  <rewriteMap name="OldSiteRewriteMap" defaultValue="">
    ...
    <add key="/a/b/oldpage" value="/x/y/newpage" />
    ...
  </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

I have a rewrite rule that uses that map to redirect URL's (we've just launched a new website and we're mapping the URL's from the old site to the corresponding URL on the new site):

```
<rule name="Redirect old site URLs">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{OldSiteRewriteMap:{PATH_INFO}}" pattern="(.+)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

When I visit http://example.com/a/b/oldpage (the old site URL) I get redirected to http://example.com/x/y/newpage - great! But when I visit http://example.com/a/b/oldpage.aspx -note the .aspx extension - I don't get redirected.

How can I tell my rewrite rule to ignore the ".aspx" extension when it's trying to map URL's using the rewrite map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker suggested the following - using a regex in the "match url" to capture everything except a possible trailing ".aspx" and then passing the capture to the rewrite map in lieu of PATH_INFO or any of the other server vars. Seems to work pretty well.

```
    <rule name="Redirect old site URLs">
      <match url="^(.+?)(\.aspx)?$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{OldSiteRewriteMap:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```